# Print triangle of numbers in python

Tags: python

Objective: i need to draw a right triangle of numbers.

I receive this result :

```
1
12     
123
1234
```

and i want to draw this shape :

```
     1
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
654321
```

and my code is :

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(0,6):
        print(" ")
    for k in range(1,i):
        print(k,end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is python 3.x version:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(0,6-i):
        print(" ", end="")

    for k in reversed(range(1,i)):
        print(k, end="")

    print("")
```

**Note:** the **end=""** ensures that print is not immediately followed by a new line.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x, it can be done like so:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(0,6-i):
        print " ",
    for k in reversed(range(1,i)):
        print k,
    print ""
```

**Note:** the comma ensures that print is not immediately followed by a new line.

Comment: Judging from `print()`, it appears OP is using python 3.x. If it were 2.x, I would suggest converting `print()` to `print ""`.